# How to scale up D3 chart on legend clicks

Tags: javascript, d3.js

3 types of data are displaying into d3 line chart ,one has high volume of data .If we disable the high volume data by clicking on legend other remaining 3 looks very small ,I would like to rescale Y axis accordingly on legend click like high chart is doing .Basically I have to redraw the chart or rescale in a generic way while clicking on legend .I have many charts .

Legend click

```
function onClick()
        {
            var sel = main.select( '.' + d3.select(this).attr('data-key')),
                selZ = zoom.selectAll( '.' + d3.select(this).attr('data-key')),
                _active = sel.property('active');
            sel.property({'active': !_active});
            sel.transition()
                .style({'opacity': (_active) ? 0 : 1, 'visibility': (_active) ? 'hidden': 'visible'});
            selZ.transition()
                .style({'opacity': (_active) ? 0 : 1, 'visibility': (_active) ? 'hidden': 'visible'});
            d3.select(this).transition()
                .style('opacity', (_active)? .4: 1 );
        }
```

Please suggest.

Comment: you will have to change the scaling function ,, and then redraw the whole chart ,, can you provide more code ???

Comment: Checkout dc.js. It has some high level charting functions - such as line charts. Out of the box it handles dynamic axis that grow and shrink to fit the data set.

Comment: this what i was looking http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24865623/redrawing-the-stack-bar-chat-on-click-on-the-toggle-legend-using-d3-js